# How to style window borders in Linux Mint w/ Cinnamon?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, themes, cinnamon

I've noticed that all the themes leave me with those large gray/metal window borders, which I really don't like.

How can I edit this, and why do most themes simply change how the taskbar looks?

Comment: Have you looked at the "Other Settings" tab in the Cinnamon Settings -> Themes dialog? It allows you to select some other options for how the borders/buttons look. That said, I don't find any of the other options better.

Comment: I actually remember being there a couple of weeks ago, also, if you would add your comment as an answer that'd be great.

Comment: Sure. There's also the option of downloading entirely new themes, some of which drastically alter the appearance. I found one (FiftyWays?) that looked good as a test for answering this question, but I just couldn't get the thing to install no matter where I put it. Oh well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the Cinnamon Settings -> Themes dialog, there is an "Other Settings" tab. On this tab you can set things such as Window theme (appearance of borders) and Icon theme.

Comment: I can't find the "Other Settings" tab on Themes dialog. I am using Mint 17.1 Rebecca

Comment: @green: I just spun up a VM, it looks like the Themes dialog itself now has the options (there are dropdowns to change Window Borders, Icons, etc).

Comment: Yes, it looks for any folder under /usr/share/themes and ~/.themes that has metacity configuration folder for borders and controls.

Answer (score 3):

Yes . This works.You need to download the themes first online. There are plenty.I used Mint-xp. Once themes are downloaded you can use path menu-->system settings--> Themes--> other settings--> change window border and control. You will get the look you desire. Thanks.

Comment: Borderless seems all the rage now, but [Windows 8](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1013223) still has visible ones to grab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed custom theme (e.g. Windows-10-master) to `/home/username/.themes` and **don't see it in `Window borders`**, enable it using terminal:

```
sudo gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.wm.preferences theme Windows-10-master
```